# golang: how to get sub element from a []interface{} alias

Tags: syntax, go

I defined a alias to []interface{}:

```
type state []interface{}
```

how to get subitems in State:

```
func test(s state) {
    // How to get 1st element in s ?
    // or How to convert s back to []interface{} ?
}

test([]interface{1, 2, 3})
```

Answer (score 1):

`test([]interface{1, 2, 3})` is wrong, it should be `test(state{1,2,3})`.

Also you access the first element in s like you would access any slice, with `s[x]`:

```
type state []interface{}

func test(s state) {
    fmt.Println(s[0])
}

func main() {
    test(state{1, 2, 3})
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/m9laQnglga)

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type state []interface{}

func (s state) item(index int) (interface{}, error) {
    if len(s) <= index {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Index out of range")
    }

    return s[index], nil
}

func main() {
    st := state{1, 2, 3}

    // get sub item
    it, err := st.item(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("First Item %v\n", it)

    // cast back to []interface{}
    items := []interface{}(st)

    fmt.Println(items)
}
```